# For boolean values is & and && equal

Tags: java

Ok is & and && equivalent for boolean values.

```
boolean t = true & false;
boolean t2 = true && false;
```

Both seem the same.  Any difference?  Is one faster, etc.?

Comment: @shmosel Clearly my question is about boolean values.  Not bitwise operations.

Comment: As is the duplicate.

Comment: @shmosel Ok, right you are.